# Django form not validating when trying to update an existing row from database

Tags: python, django, validation, django-forms, django-views

I am working on my first Django project.
But I get following errors:

**edit_file template**

```
                <form method="POST" action="{% url 'edit_file' file.id %}">
                {% csrf_token %}

                {{ form.errors }}
                {{ form.non_field_errors }}

                {% for hidden_field in form.hidden_fields %}
                    {{ hidden_field.errors }}
                    {{ hidden_field }}
                {% endfor %}

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="id_name" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"> File Name </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        {% render_field form.name|add_class:"form-control" %}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">File Path</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        {% render_field form.directory_path|add_class:"form-control" %}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {% render_field form.script_code|add_class:"form-control" %}
                    <pre id="id_script_code" style="height: 40pc;">{{ form.script_code }}</pre>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mr-2">Save Changes</button>
                <a href="{% url 'list_files_from_version' file.version_id %}" class="btn btn-light">Back</a>

            </form>
```

**Views.py**

```
def edit_file(request, id):
    instance = get_object_or_404(File, id=id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EditFileForm(request.POST, instance=instance)  
        if form.is_valid():
            print('Form validation => True')
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse('<h1> database updated! </h1>')
        else:
            print('Form validation => False')
        file = File.objects.latest('id')
        context = {'file': file, "form": form}
        return render(request, 'edit_file.html', context)
    else:
        instance = get_object_or_404(File, id=id)
        form = EditFileForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
        file = File.objects.latest('id')
        context = {'file': file, "form": form}
        return render(request, 'edit_file.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class EditFileForm(ModelForm):
    # field_order = ['field_1', 'field_2']

    class Meta:
        print("forms.py 1")
        model = File
        fields = ('name', 'script_code', 'directory_path','version')

    def clean(self):
        print("forms.py 2")
        cleaned_data = super(EditFileForm, self).clean()
        name = cleaned_data.get('name')
        print("cleaned data: ", cleaned_data)
```

**Models:**

Version id point to a version which contains multiple files.

```
  class File(models.Model):
    # Incrementing ID (created automatically)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    script_code = models.TextField()  # max juiste manier?
    directory_path = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    version = models.ForeignKey('Version', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta(object):
        db_table = 'file'  # table name


class Version(models.Model):
    # Incrementing ID (created automatically)
    version_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    pending_update = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, editable=False)
    modification_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    connecthor = models.ForeignKey('ConnecThor', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.connecthor_id
```

***The problem:***

form.is_valid() keeps failing. My view returns one error.
***version: This field is required.** But I don't know how to fix this. Users should only be able to update 3 of the 5 data fields. So there is no reason to show the PK or FK in the template.

Comment: You need to show the definitions of your form and model.

Comment: @DanielRoseman done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've included version in the list of fields in your form, but you aren't outputting it in the template so there is no means of providing it. Since the model field does not specify blank=True, it is a required field, hence the error.

If you don't want users to be able to modify this field, you should remove it from that list of fields under Meta.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have version in your template. Your model field for version does not say it can have null values. Hence your form validation fails. Include it in your template or remove the field from EditFileForm class's Meta class in forms.py